# Video in picturebox c#

Tags: c#, forms, video, picturebox

I have a problem retrieving my video in the picture box in my second form.
This is my code

Main.cs

```
  private void start_video()
    {

        while (!needClose)
        {
            video.capture();
            pictureBox1.Image = ImageFrame.video;
        }
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        camera = new Camera();
        camera.Show();
    }
```

This is my class *(of course there is a function that set video)*

```
  public class ImageFrame
  {
   public static Image video { get; set; }
  }
```

And this is my Camera.cs

```
 public partial class Camera : Form
{
    private bool test = false;

    public Camera()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        returnVideo();
    }

   private void returnVideo()
    {
        while (!test)
        {
            pictureBox2.Image = ImageFrame.video;
        }
    }
```

The video works fine in pictureBox1, but when I click on button1 to open the new form retrieving the same video of pictureBox1 it just freeze. 
Why? If I don't use the *while* it would just show a frame but I need the video (that is from the camera, so in live view).

Comment: Do not use ShowDialog to open new form!

Comment: I'm using Form.show, I don't get what are you saying

Answer (score 0):

This blocks the event-loop to run, so on every window change UI update will stop and therefore freeze.

```
    while (!test) // = while(true)
    {
        pictureBox2.Image = ImageFrame.video;
    }
```

Use a timer to update the picture every 50 msec or less.

EDIT: Some pseudo code:

```
timer1.Interval=50;
timer1.Tick+=timer1_Tick;
timer1.Start();

void timer1_Tick(..)
{
  pictureBox2.Image = ImageFrame.video;
}
```

This also reduces CPU load.